# How to replace a list of images with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, replace, src, sliders

I'd like to replace the images in a list item by changing the name from `"portrait.jpg"` to `"landscape.jpg"` follow by sequence numbers.

For example:

```
<img src="images/slider_01_portrait.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_02_portrait.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_03_portrait.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_04_portrait.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_05_portrait.jpg">
```

Change to ↓

```
<img src="images/slider_01_landscape.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_02_landscape.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_03_landscape.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_04_landscape.jpg">
<img src="images/slider_05_landscape.jpg">
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="slider fullscreen">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider_01_portrait.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider_02_portrait.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider_03_portrait.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider_04_portrait.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider_05_portrait.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('img[src*="portrait"]').attr('src', function (i, oldSrc) {
    return oldSrc.replace('portrait', 'landscape');
});` [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/x2d3muzL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var img = $('img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  var src = $(img[i]).prop('src').replace('portrait', 'landscape');
  $(img[i]).prop('src', src);
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
var ul = $("<ul/>", {class: 'slides'});
$("img").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("portrait", "landscape"));
    var li = $("<li/>");
    li.append(this);
    ul.append(li);
});
$(".slider").append(ul);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/153/)